SMTP server constant blocking list
I am monitoring a Paragon Insights server (Healthbot), Ubuntu system with kubernets environment, one of the containers called Alert has installed in this the Exim4 tool as MTA to send email notifications alerts to different users from different domains. Lately we noticed that the mails were arriving out of time not to all destinations, reviewing the Exim logs we had SMTP errors because the public IPs used by the server to transfer these emails to remote SMTP servers were blocked.
TO:example@example.com: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [201.236.131.114] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/201.236.131.114 AS(1440) [SJ5PEPF000001ED.n2T21:36:44.023Z 08DD0153AEC02232]
TO:example@example.com: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [190.151.38.234] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/190.151.38.234 AS(1440) [DB3PEPF0000885A.12T21:36:43.924Z 08DD00F2FBE643C8]
Currently, the server uses a HELO FQDN of “onnetfibra.com”, with the sender user root@onnetfibra.com. From what I have been reading i think the problem is that when the remote server performs an rDNS on the server IPs, it does not present a declared one or PTR with the domain. On the other hand, if the remote SMTP server performs a DNS Forwarding to the onnetfibra.com domain, it will point to another IP of the DNS provider 129.151.109.154.
Considering this, is it possible that with the management of the PTR with the provider of the public IPs, this blocklist problem could be solved? I am confused because the details of the blocking info points to a CSS blocklist and comments on server configuration, but it looks fine: "Please correct your HELO 'onnetfibra.com' and if needed, configure your mail server with correct DNS (forward and reverse) and HELO/EHLO values. Correcting an invalid HELO or a HELO/forward DNS lookup mismatch will stop the IP from being listed again." Or could I be missing something that needs to be managed to prevent public IPs from being blocklisted and continue with the mail rejection problem?
Currently we only get a few emails and other users may not get any. There are many Exim bounce logs.
2024-11-15 15:03:42 1tBxrG-0098TI-SO -> example@example.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=example.mail.protection.outlook.com [52.101.40.0] X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes K C="250 2.6.0 E1tBxrG-0098TI-SO@OnNetFibra.com [InternalId=26701811681766, Hostname=CO1PR15MB5100.namprd15.prod.outlook.com] 10043 bytes in 0.068, 144.005 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery"
Please help me to understand this issue better, I can get logs of what is needed to review.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that we managed to remove these IPs from the block list but it took hours and they were blocked again.

Are you in control of the IP address you are sending from (is that address used by you and only you, and are you able to publish appropriate PTR)?

Have you checked that you're not sending spam?

You are not supposed to ask blocklist providers to remove an address before you have understood and confirmed as resolved whatever caused the listing. Spamhaus is fairly lenient, some others will quickly stop offering that once they see abuse of their self-service removal.

@anx Yes, both IPs are the organization's own, both delivered by different ISPs.

@anx Thank you for the clarification, I do have it in mind. My idea is to understand the cause of this problem and once fixed, request the removal again.

@vidarlo The content of the mail is about alerts generated in routers, with hostname, device id, message, etc. This is sent to a large number of destination mails, regarding spam possibly the servers will consider it as this because from what I see in AboutMy.email with a test mail I sent from the server, SPF, DKIM and Reverse DNS are failing.

I didn't ask if the messages you know about is spam. Are you sure you are not sending spam? Check your logs.

If you are being blocked by Spamhaus it is because people are receiving emails from your MTA they do not want.

From what I have been reading i think the problem is that when the remote server performs an rDNS on the server IPs, it does not present a declared one or PTR with the domain.

No.
A long time ago, people tried to address spam by using a mechanism known as RMX - they expected the FROM address on the envelope and header to match the PTR record of the connecting SMTP client. This was rejected as an IETF standard, and subsequently gave rise to SPF - a more sensible mechanism where senders could publish the legitimate adresses of their MTAs in DNS. Sadly there are still mailserver out there implementing the defunct mechanism.
OTOH the mapping between the PTR record and the HELO name presented by the MTA still matters (but this has never been formalized as a standard).
Other mail providers will not tell you why they reject email. Why make it easier for spammers to reverse engineer their defences?
Check you are NOT running an open relay. Implement SPF and preferably DMARK and DKIM for your domains. Audit your mail logs.

Checking there is no open relay since only the server itself with its user host root@domain.com is the only one that sends these emails. Checking the logs there is no spam, only necessary emails.

Now, if one does a lookup to the domain of the organization this passes all the security mechanisms such as SPF, DMARK and DKIM, but the problem is that the server internally with Exim uses the same FQDN @domain of the organization, but with a different public IP and this obviously generates the failure of rDNS and security mechanisms classifying emails as spam, besides that the server internally has no DNS configuration. Now I have the confusion to know how to solve this?

I was thinking if I would have to configure the DNS of the organization (Oracle) to resolve the FQDN set in the MTA pointing to the IP of the server? Would this ensure that the MTA discovers the DNS mail server for the domain (managed by Oracle provider) based on the FQDN of the Exim4 host and finally the Exim4 agent forwards the email to this DNS mail server? Or is it necessary to configure an internal DNS on the same server and implement there the security mechanisms for the MTA?

I am completely confused by your description of how this is configured. Maybe you should edit your question providing the actual values configured (you can change the domain name to "example.com" but that does mean we can't find the data you've omitted).
